Dealing with stale table statistics in postgres
I have a single table where some data it inserted and processed in bulks. Processing (UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE) starts immediately on that table. Generally, the database is able to pick the optimal execution plan for processing, but it just happens that sometimes the database picks a sub-optimal plan.
There is a large mismatch in estimated and actual rows in execution plans (from auto-explain extension): (cost=0.12..2.34 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.052..53.734 rows=79816 loops=1).
It gets corrected a few moments later, and DB starts picking optimal plans, but by then my service is already below SLO.
What are the strategies to deal with that?

Well, explicite call of ANALYZE immedietely after the DML statement...

To avoid that, you should run an explicit ANALYZE of the table inside the transaction that performs the bulk operation.  That way, nobody ever sees stale statistics.
It is also a good idea to run an explicit VACUUM on the table just after the transaction is finished.

That way I'm delaying the processing. But I get it. Need to delay something.

ANALYZE is not a very intense operation.

Actually solved by SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off. It's a single table with a single index. I don't need the DB to try anything smart.

Sure, whatever works for you.
